# How to define a trait with methods accepting any subtype of a particular trait

Tags: scala, methods, parameters, overriding, traits

I have two traits

```
trait AppModel {}
trait ModelOperations {
  def get(model: AppModel): Option[AppModel]
  def create(model: AppModel): Boolean
}
```

And implemented classes

```
class User extends AppModel {
  val id = "xyz"
  val name = "abc"
}

class UserOperations extends ModelOperations {
   override def get(user: User) : Option[User] = {
    // get a new user object by filtering existing parameters
    return None
   }
   override def create(user: User): Boolean = { 
      // do something
      return false
   }
}
```

However when I try to compile, I get `method get overrides nothing` and `method create overrides nothing` errors

What I intent to do is: declare an interface `I` with methods that will accept parameters of any class `T` that extends `AppModel` and return `T`
And any class that extends `I` can have methods that accept exactly class `T` as parameters (and not any other class `R` of `AppModel`)

How do I go about this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `type` field with a bound, that you can refine in the concrete implementation. Here's an example

```
trait AppModel
trait ModelOperations {
  type T <: AppModel
  def get(model: T): Option[T]
}

class User extends AppModel

class UserOperations extends ModelOperations {
  type T = User
  def get(user: User): Option[User] = None
}
```

Comment: This is clean and works. Thanks. So I guess it is possible to use multipe types  as well as in `type T<: Model1  type U <: Model2` and so on ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
trait AppModel {}
trait ModelOperations {
  def get[T<:AppModel](model: T): Option[T]
  def create[T<:AppModel](model: T): Boolean
}
```

class User extends AppModel {
  val id = "xyz"
  val name = "abc"
}

class UserOperations extends ModelOperations {
   override def get[User](user: User) : Option[User] = {
    // get a new user object by filtering existing parameters
    return None
   }
   override def create[User](user: User): Boolean = { 
      // do something
      return false
   }
}

Comment: Thanks. This works. However the solution by http://stackoverflow.com/users/846273/gabriele-petronella is much cleaner to write.